# Docker run failed with Error response from daemon

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I simply run the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

and after pulling all images returns this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint webserver
>   (ac5719bc0e95ead1a4ec6b6ae437c4c0b8a9600ee69ecf72e73f8d2d12020f97): 
>   Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80:  unexpected error
>   (Failure EADDRINUSE).

Here is my docker Version info:

```
Client:
Version:      1.12.0
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   8eab29e
Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:15:28 2016
OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.12.0
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   8eab29e
Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:15:28 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't provide informations such as Docker version, system or docker processes running so I assume the most likely situation.

The output contains: `Failure EADDRINUSE`. It means that port `80` is used by something else. You can use [`lsof -i TCP:80`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=lsof%20-i%20TCP%3A80) to check which process is listening on that port. If there is nothing running on the port, it might be some issue with Docker. For example the one with [not releasing ports immediately](https://forums.docker.com/t/port-mappings-are-not-released/10565).

Comment: After some study I found the solution. I changed the dns port to 8.8.8.8 and it started working. On Mac Go to System Preferences-> Network -> select the connected network-> Advanced-> DNS-> and add a port 8.8.8.8 and it will work.

Comment: I had the same issue and tried this solutions but didn't work. This worked for me `sudo apachectl stop` then run docker. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Salam so Apache was running on that port as I wrote in the answer